# Do dropbox javascript sdk is supported with ionic3 ?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dropbox

Do any one have idea regrading the integration of dropbox javascript sdk to ionic 3 app...

Note: i have found some sample example using http endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dropbox Api to work with Ionic.

Here is a good tutorial to begin with:

Part 1: https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-ionic-2-with-the-dropbox-api-part-1/

Part 2: https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-ionic-2-with-the-dropbox-api-part-2/

Comment: thank you ashfaq, I have already seen this tutorial he is using simple http services but i want to use javascript sdk.

Comment: what is that you cannot do with dropbox api ?